# React native init error: Couldn't find package "error-ex" on the "npm" registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm already working on a react native project. However, I need to create a new sample project. Below **error** occurred when I tried to initiate the new sample project using `react-native init Project001` and I have already installed **react native cli** globally. Can any one help with this ?

Thanks for your help!

```
$ react-native init Project001
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in D:\Sample project\Project001
Using yarn v1.21.1
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.21.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native > fbjs-scripts > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > fbjs > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > metro-babel-register > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
error Couldn't find package "error-ex" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "errorhandler" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:321:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Error: Couldn't find package "error-ex" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:321:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
{ Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
    at run (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:217:7
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\node_modules\prompt\lib\prompt.js:316:32
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:142:25
    at assembler (C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\node_modules\prompt\lib\prompt.js:313:9)
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\node_modules\prompt\lib\prompt.js:322:32
    at C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\node_modules\prompt\lib\prompt.js:597:5
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 6592,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null }
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
```

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.

Comment: [npm has a problem in installing certain packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWCWi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is still there ? i'm experiencing this kind of error :

```
Error: Couldn't find package "error-ex" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:50302:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:321:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: Yes it's still having issues, I'm getting similar errors here in Toronto. (Apparently some areas of the world work and others don't, so if you really need to install something now, try a VPN or something)

Comment: I was having the same issue. Now I have connected to the US using a VPN and this issue is not shown. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this Dear in you terminal `npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`